# Seeding and Branching projects using entity framework migrations

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a project using entity framework code first 4.3 using migrations.
When running locally my web.config is configured to target a database initialzer which implements `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>` which seeds my development database with test data but also populating various 'static' lookuptable data first time it's run.

Once the development database has been created any subsequent changes to the database is done adding migrations to the project and updating the database with the 'updata-database' PS command.

When I'm happy with project I deploy the code with webdeploy but copy the database manually since webdeploy doesn't include the migrations table. When deploying I use a web.config transform to set a new database initializer that implements `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext>`. This would then apply new code based migrations deployed afterwards.
This is all working reasonably well but I have concerns whether this is the best approach to initialize my db not only with test data but also data that required to run the application.
What I'm looking for is a good way to create that initial seed data without having to hook it into the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>` but instead hooking it into Migrations.
I realise there is a seed method on the configuration class but seeing as it's updating the database with every migration this is not desirable solution.

The project is in TFS and from time to time I need to create a new branch of this project which is essence is a clone of the first. When running this locally for the first time the database doesn't exist yet but will be created and seeded as explained earlier. Biggest problem now is that schema changes previously handled through migrations will now be applied when the database is created for the first time. If I then try to add a new migration file and run 'update-database' I run into a wall since it can't run previous migrations because those changes was already applied when the database was created. I can only Imagine I'm doing something wrong here or simply missed a trick.

In conclusion I'm looking for information regarding

1. Best way to seed initial test data & required application data when creating the database for the first time using migrations.
2. Best way to overcome problems when branching a project containing code migrations and having to create the database for the first time.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best way to seed initial test data & required application data when
>   creating the database for the first time using migrations.

Migration configuration has `Seed` method which exists exactly to solve this problem. In this method you can use `AddOrUpdate` extension method to intitialize your core data. The extension method will first check if record already exists in database and either update it or insert a new record.

Comment: I'm aware of the mentioned seed method. My concern with using it is that it executes every time a migration is run.
Some of my initial core data would/could be changed through the application when it's running and I don't want it to reset if a new migration is added.
If you have a good method of wrapping the Seed method in the configuration class so it only executes on the 'InitialCreate' migration i suppose it would work but I haven't found any good way to do this.

Comment: It is your responsibility to ensure that calling `Seed` method is repeatable - `AddOrUpdate` can help with it. If you are not able to ensure that add custom seeding SQL statements directly to your `Up` method in migrations.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but one of the many reason to use entity framework was to avoid having to write what could be relatively complex SQL insert statements. as opposed to seeding through the context. I'm working on an alternative solution and will post is once/if checks out working.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that initializing your database using the Seed method is a mistake for anything but very small and simple sets of data. The reason is that as you say, it simply gets run too often.  We have moved data initialization out of the application and into the installation process instead.  We just built a set of methods that use normal entity framework code to create the data needed.  This way, we do not have to worry about performance and can more easily write tests that validate the data creation code.

For initializing the database during development, we have a set of unit tests that will run the same code that the installer does. Developers simply run the unit tests and their database will be initialized properly.